# Google Chat QoS settings

Tags: router, qos, voice-chat

Has anyone figured out what the correct ports are for QoS settings for Google Chat **voice** converstations? I need to boost the priority of these packets on my home network, but I can't find any docs on what to set.

I'm hoping that someone out their has either found it or figured it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From [How do I allow my internal XMPP client or server to connect to the Talk service?](http://code.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=62464):

> To allow full voice and video interoperability with the Google Talk
>   service, you must:
>
> - Allow your XMPP clients to connect to all IP addresses contained in
>     the IP blocks listed in Google's ASN of 15169, on:
>
>   - UDP ports 4893, 19295, and 19302
>       or
>   - TCP port 19294

The voice traffic goes over port `19295`. So i created a high priority rule for:

- **Protocol:** `UDP`
- **Direction:** `out`
- **Destination Port:** 19295
- **Protocol:** `UDP`
- **Direction:** `in`
- **Source Port:** 19295

---

Or just use Process Monitor, filter it by

- Process Name: `googlevoicechat.exe`
- Activity: Network

and watch the screenfuls of UDP voice traffic:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As of today, there are two scenarios:

1. Google Hangouts and calling a regular phone number from within gmail: UDP ports 19305 to 19309 (https://support.google.com/a/answer/1279090?hl=en)
2. For a **computer to computer** voice call (started with the phone icon in gmail, not a hangout without video), the connection is from your ip address to the ip address of the computer of the person you're talking with and the ports (source and destination) appear to be chosen randomly (I will update this answer if observations suggest that there is a range)

Answer (score 1):

June 16, 2013:  This seems to have changed since 2011.  I couldn't find any current documentation.

Did some work with a packet sniffer today (Wireshark) dialing out from the Google Talk Plugin under Firefox 21.0 running on Windows 7.

Looks like the call setup is now done through standard HTTPS (TCP 443).

In several test calls, RTP (voice) packets were sent to UDP destination port 19305.  I have no idea whether that will stay the same.

The Differentiated Services Field (DSCP) of the RTP packets is 0, so that can't be used for OoS setup.

On my router running Tomato, in the OoS settings, I have classified application Layer 7 (RTP) as Highest.  Unfortunately it is not detecting the Google Voice packets; they were passing as Low priority. So I added a new entry for UDP Destination 19305 and the RTP traffic was properly prioritized.

Answer (score 0):

**I figured it would be helpful to add this info from Google support:**

> Hangouts are adaptive in the ways they attempt to establish a network
>   connection between a participant on your network and the Google
>   conference servers.
>
> The connection methods are attempted in this **preferenced order:** A
>   **UDP** connection from the participant to Google on ports **19302 through 19309**
>
> A **TCP** connection from the participant to Google on ports **19305
>   through 19309**
>
> A **TCP** connection from the participant to Google on **port 80**
>
> A **TCP** connection from the participant to Google on **port 443
>   (SSL)**
>
> The ideal connection for a user to make to a hangout is through UDP.
>   To allow this connection attempt to succeed, you must allow routes
>   from your network to UDP ports 19302 through 19309.
>
> At a minimum, your corporate network must allow access to the Internet
>   on TCP ports 80 and 443 in order for hangouts to work.
>
> In addition, we recommend opening these additional ports on TCP for
>   the following clients:
>
> Ports Clients
>
> **5222, 5223, 5224 XMPP clients**
>
> **5228 and 5229   Android phones**
>
> **5269 XMPP federation**
>
> Consult the documentation from your firewall vendor if you need
>   information about opening UDP and TCP ports.
>
> Notes
>
> **All traffic back to the client from our conference servers will originate >from the same port that the client is sending to, and be directed back to the >port that the client is sending from.**
>
> The UDP traffic consists of STUN, RTP, and RTCP packets, with SRTP encrypted >data payloads.
>
> We are unable to provide any specific IP addresses for our conference servers.

**SOURCE:**
https://support.google.com/a/answer/1279090?hl=en